# RegEx for positive number + greater than zero an decimal (0.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a field in javascript to have at least 1 and should be positive number or decimal.

Examples:

```
1
1.1
0.1
10.10
```

My current regex looks like this:

```
var _RegEx = /^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/;
```

Comment: How about just `+val > 0`?

Comment: Would also need `isFinite(val)` assuming `Infinity`  should be disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple:**

```
 /^\+?(\d*[1-9]\d*\.?|\d*\.\d*[1-9]\d*)$/.test(x)
```

**Simpler:**

```
0 < parseInt(x, 10) && parseInt(x, 10) < Infinity
```

**Simplest:**

```
0 < +x && +x < Infinity && !/[^\d.+]/.test(x)
```

Thanks to Jack, the last one is not so simple anymore. :/

Comment: There's something wrong: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^+?([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|.[0-9]+)$/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: Fixed. Needed to escape literal +.

Comment: Note that `'0xff'` will "work" in the "simplest case" but not in the two others :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\+?(\d*[1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9]\d*)?)$
```

regex to match:

1. any number greater than zero
2. with or without decimal number
3. not match if number is not inserted followed by (.)

Comment: This doesn't match `0.1` but it should according to OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((0?0?\.([1-9]\d*|0[1-9]\d*))|(([1-9]|0[1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?))$
```

---

```
12.34
00.34
0.34
109.341
0.00 (not matched)
.9
9
09
0 (not matched)
```