# Regular expression to accept only decimals and numbers including zero point decimals and restrict 0

Tags: c#, regex

i need to write an regular expression for a text box to enter an amount. like currency. it should accept decimals and integers. and also restrict 0 and minus numbers. this is my regular expression. but it wont allow decimals.

```
"nonZero": { "regex": "^[1-9][0-9]*$",
                    "alertText": "* This field cannot be zero",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                    "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx for positive number + greater than zero an decimal (0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627995/regex-for-positive-number-greater-than-zero-an-decimal-0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tink you had forget to add decimal part to regex.
It must be somethig like this:

"^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$"

The backslash (escapr character) is to tell that the dot (.) Is litterally the dot, because dot have some meanig to regex.
The parantesis is to group some regex part to gether.

The question mark tells that this group may or may not exists.

So the regex is a sequence of character that first one is 1-9, some chars between 0-9, and a dot & some digits that may or may not exists.

But pay attention that the dot is in parantesis so if it exists, decimal must exist too. The plus sign tells that at least, one digit must exist if dot exists

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. i checked your regex and it is accepting decimal points and restricting 0. but it is also restricting 0.1 and 0. decimals. i need to accept those also.

Comment: Try this :^(0*\.0*[1-9]+)|(([1-9][0-9])*(\.[0-9]+)?)$

Comment: this restricts 1.0

Comment: this :^(0*\.0*[1-9]+)|(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?)$

Comment: yes. this works fine. finally got the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be using following

```
^(([1-9]{1}|[\d]{2,})(\.[\d]+)?)$|^(0\.[\d]+)$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTKcOo/2/)

Where

- `^(0\.[\d]+)$` => for numbers where `0 < x < 1`
- `^(([1-9]{1}|[\d]{2,})(\.[\d]+)?)$` Rest of positive numbers

Output

```
2131 => Valid
2.3434 => Valid
0.45 => Valid
123 => Valid

234. => Invalid
.5234 => Invalid
a => Invalid
-123123 => Invalid
```

Comment: this woks fine in regex tester. but when i applied this to java script code and call it from asp.net code. it restricts the 0.1 or any other decimals starting from 0. this is my code.  
 $('#<% = txtAmount.ClientID %>').addClass('validate[custom[nonZero]]');               
then i wrote the above regex in js file

Answer (score 1):

This will work and is the shortest solution:

```
^-?\d+$|^-?\d+.\d+$
```

See the example here --> [RegexTester](https://regex101.com/r/uTKcOo/3)